# Tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 dual with a Wndows 8.1 Neither system boots

Tags: boot

Well, I think I erased, corrupted, destroyed or how you want to call it, the UEFIs boot section, system, files. I have:

```
Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Memory : 3964MB(1333)
Mother Board : Aspire M3985
BIOS Version : P11-A0
CPU Identification : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
CPU Generic Name : Intel64 Family 6 Model 10 Stepping 9
CPU Vendor : GenuineIntel 
OS Name : Microsoft Windows 8.1
OS Language : 日本語 (日本 Japanese)
OS Version : 6.3.9600
OS Type : 64 bit.
```

First I freed 65GB of disk space by shrinking the windows partitions, and I turned off secure boot in the UEFI/Bios setup (I formated the 65GB to ext3 in windows but it was a bad idea.) Then setup Ubuntu 16.04.1 Desktop amd386, after finished, on boot no select menu appeared, and win booted up as if Ubuntu was never installed.

Next I tried `Boot-repair` (I think here I did something to the UEFI thing) . Next boot the message **REBOOT AND SELECT PROPER DEVICE OR INSERT BOOT MEDIA IN SELECTED BOOT DEVICE AND PRESS A KEY
** ... this is still happening.

Next tried `Boot-Repair` again, and reading troubleshooting in ASK try to update, reinstall Grub and nothing. Then reintalled the Ubuntu package and nothing, downloaded the windows from ms, try to repair or reinstall windows (Windows aborted becouse the file system on hdd is not compatible not a GPT partition), then try a Debian version and installed it, still always the same message at boot, and going worst after debian installment, boot on legacy mode can be do only by pressing F12 acceding to the boot menu and selecting the device(dvd), HDD same message, legacy or uefi mode.

Now i set the silent boot of UEFI/Bios off and discover an error message  after the discovery of the  periferals hdd, cd/dvd, usb ports etc, that says:
FAILED TO OPEN  \EFI\BOOT\Mo
MANAGER.efi - Not Found
Failed  to load imafe \EFI\BOOT\Mokmanager.efi : Not Found
Failed to start MokManager : Not Found

Is there are a way to restore the UEFI? fdisk output is:

```
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FF3FC7DE-FE1B-4D9C-B145-A9FAB7FB2561

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    821247    819200   400M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     821248   1435647    614400   300M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1435648   1697791    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    1697792 334507212 332809421 158.7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  469983232 470917119    933888   456M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda6  470917120 471660543    743424   363M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7  471660544 943218687 471558144 224.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda8  943218688 976773119  33554432    16G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda9  334508032 459507711 124999680  59.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda10 459507712 469983231  10475520     5G Linux swap

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

I want at least one of either Ubuntu or win system operating. I lost windows partition on my attemp to reinstall it but i have a full backup of drive c: 158.7G half on drive d: 224.9G and the rest uploaded to the cloud.

Comment: Are you generaly a windows or a Ubuntu user....what do you like better?

Comment: I am windows user, i did the ubuntu installation to make a try. First kiss to the linux OS.

Comment: I would recommend you to install VirtualBox and make an Ubuntu virtual machine  so you can't do any damage to your host machine and you can test almost everything and even work in that VM

Comment: Yeah. Well I'm sorry for that.

Comment: That was only my personal opinion and comment... I think there is no help for that...OP will probably need to reinstall everything or in best case he could fix the boot loader for windows so he could startup windows IF windows was first OS installed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Ubuntu 18.10 on XPS 15 - EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup of Windows, I generally recommend wiping the drive and reinstalling. Format it as GPT for UEFI, and reinstall Windows.

After that you can install Ubuntu. You have a UEFI system (don't use CSM(!), and disable secure boot), so follow the instructions in this thread:

> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Sorry you had to experience so many issues with your first taste of linux.

If you really want to be lazy, you can use these UEFI WUBI installers (installs Ubuntu as a disk image on Windows, and creates a UEFI entry):

> https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki

Download the 16.04 ISO, put it in the same folder as the installer, and install. You can expand the disk size >30GB later. Reboot and select the -UEFI UBUNTU- entry in your BIOS Boot Options, and boot.

**Wubi isn't recommended as a full-use installation, but is a safer and faster (than a Virtual Machine) alternative for users who wish to get their feet wet with Ubuntu.**

Comment: @user601087 Good luck! Make sure to always keep backups. They will save your life, especially when working with linux.

Comment: snif snif i formatted all the HDD, and installed Linux Mint as stand alone OS, no luck the same Rebbot and select..........   message on boot.

Comment: Can you boot into the HDD by pressing "Boot Options" and selecting your hard drive?