# Ubuntu 18.10 failed installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, squashfs

I just tried switching from windows 10 to linux and had decided to go with Ubuntu.  I went through the installation steps on ubuntus website (using Rufus and such to format the usb)  and completed the installation to replace my windows 10.  It then prompted me to to reboot my PC, I continued when it started to reboot I received a full page of squashFS errors that filled the screen and then my PC turned off.  Upon turning it on again I got this message.

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mm64.efi - Not Found Failed to load image
\EFI\BOOT\mm64.efi - Not Found Failed to Start MokManager: Not Found 
something has seriously gone wrong: Import_Mok_stat()Failed
:Not Found
```

And then My PC turns off
I have opened Bios with f2, and have also truned it on and used f12 to choose to boot through usb. 
I have gone through an disabled the secure boot in bios and have reformated and put a new version of ubuntu downloaded from the dev website onto the usb(same as the first time) but I still get the same message. It's a real shame because I wanted to try out this OS and after thinking it over for a while I took the plunge and now my PC doesn't work. I feel like there is no looking back at this point so If anyone knows how to help much would be appreciated. I am excited to learn more about Linux.

```
 My PC is a Lenovo Y150p


Bios version    74cn44ww (v3.05)
EC Version      74ec44ww (v3.05)
CPU             Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700mq CPU @2.40ghz
System Memory   8.192gb
Harddisk        ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB
ODD             PLDS   DVD-RW DU8A5SH
Windows License STD
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me out!

Comment: Did you not install in [UEFI mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).

Comment: To be honest with you, I am very, very new to this.  I am not sure what I booted in I believe it was BIOS because I opened what was called the BIOS manager to select the USB to Boot and install the OS.  I am not sure how one switches between the two.

Comment: Use the link I gave.

Comment: After reading the information on UEFI mode I am sure that I did install in uefi mode.

Comment: You have to [disable fast boot in Windows](https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10). You should be able to boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. This may also be a bug like [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1798171).

Comment: Boot from your flash drive then open terminal and run command `sudo parted -l`. Add output to your post.

Comment: Fast boot was disabled in windows prior to install. Unfortunately, I can't open the terminal, and I also can't boot windows from UEFI boot menu, I installed Ubuntu and this error occured at the end of the install durring the restart. This os was meant to replace my windows 10 os, so I didn't choose the dual boot option but to replace windows. Thus no option to boot windows. Currently I am using a friends Mac PC to type this.  Prehaphs a little foolish of me I am away from home for a few days so once I'm home I will try to reinstall windows 10 like the bellow commenter suggested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Ubuntu 18.10 on XPS 15 - EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem with an HP laptop.  I solved it by going dual boot.  Since you completely erased your hard drive installing uBuntu and already activated windows 10 (assumed) then I'll introduce you to the steps I made to create a Ubuntu Server 18.04, except you'll continue to install Ubuntu Desktop instead of Server.

1. Download a current Microsoft Media Creation Tool and get an ISO of the latest Windows 10 build.  Use Rufus to format a USB flash drive to boot.  When you boot into the windows installation environment and get to the install now button, at the bottom left corner, you'll see Repair Your Computer. Click into that link and you'll be show a list of options, go into Troubleshoot then Advanced Options, select Command Prompt.  Type in the following:
   diskpart then ENTER key.  You'll get to the disk partitioning environment, then type: list disk ENTER , this will show you a list of disks available.  You will generally see two disks or two volumes, the flash drive and the hard drive.  Look for your hard drive which is usually disk 0 (zero) and type:  select disk 0 ENTER.  Now type: clean ENTER. This will turn your HDD into a raw drive with no formatting.  Type: Exit ENTER to leave the environment.  Then type: Exit ENTER to leave the command environment.  This will bring you back to the Windows 10 installation, choose to shut-down your PC.
2. Boot with the Windows 10 flash drive you already made. and follow the Windows 10 installation process, when you get to the Product Key choose Skip or Don't have key, Use Custom:  Install windows only, Where to install Windows, here is where you will create a New partition to install windows 10.  I allocated 70GB or 70000 MB for windows out of my 500GB HDD.  Select the partition you made for Windows 10 and continue with installation, when you are interviewed by windows to set-up an account, create a local account only, resist using the e-mail option.  When you are presented with customize settings, turn everything off, and don't use Cortana.
3. Windows 10 should now be up and running, update windows 10, while it's updating, turn off fast shutdown by going into windows start button, settings, system, power & sleep, additional power settings, Choose what closing the lid does.  Here you'll see that Turn on fast startup is greyed out, so above you'll see Change settings that are currently unavailable, click on that then you'll be able to uncheck Turn on fast startup, click save changes.  Right-mouse click on the start button and select Disk Management.   Here you'll see Disk 0 with the unallocated space, we are going to turn this into a raw partition so that Ubuntu will see it and use it.  Right-mouse click on unallocated and select new simple volume.   Accept auto size click on NEXT, Do not assign a drive letter NEXT, Do not format this volume NEXT, click on FINISH.  Close this window and return back to windows updates where you'll wait until windows 10 updates and reboots and then check updates again and reboot if needed, now you're ready to installed Ubuntu.  Shutdown your PC.
4. I have not gone through the Ubuntu Desktop installation process because I was focused on installing server, so I lack that experience.  But looking at screen shots from Ask Ubuntu, I can see that you can select Something Else under Installation Type.  Then select the Raw partition that we prepared earlier and format it to use EXT4.  Continue with the Ubuntu installation at this point.
5. Side note for Ubuntu Server Installers, doesn't pertain to you but will show up in a search for installing server 18.04.  I had to use the traditional installer for the server in order to get to an area where I can select my raw partition.  By using the common installer, I didn't get the "Something Else," I got the use all of the drive option only, which I chose at first but then my HP laptop wouldn't boot up, did this twice (once with an unallocated space and 2nd with a RAW partition), so I learned my lesson and went the dual boot way with the traditional installer.

Comment: Thank you for the information I will try this out. You mentioned it is assumed that I activated windows 10, I have not been able to access my PC no windows 10 or anything the only options I get as far as booting is booting through my usb which brings me to the error above and also to boot through  EFI Nework 0 for ipv6, and EFI Network 0 for Ipv4 which also does nothing

Comment: Your intro said "tried switching from windows 10 to linux" so I thought you upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8, which comes with your laptop by default.  And I know that you wiped out your hard drive because you wrote, "completed the installation to replace my windows 10," which means you accepted the default that erased your entire HDD.  Good news.  When you install Windows 10 this time around, continue w/o key, the windows 8 SLIC in your BIOS will activate Win 10 with a digital license, remember to choose the same Win 10 version same as what was installed on your laptop previously.