# Dual boot: either no bcd, or no grub

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 18.10 alongside Windows 10.

When I boot, I see grub, and I can boot into Ubuntu.
But if I choose Windows from the grub menu, I get an error message saying that BCD is missing.
Now, I can fix that with my Macrium Reflect CD, if I boot it EFI (my AMI BIOS is very temperamental about booting removable media as EFI). It fixes Windows, but then, grub is gone, and the only way I can get to Ubuntu is by manually selecting it in BIOS.

I tried running boot-repair. When I run it from my Ubuntu installation, it complains that I did not boot efi. If I run it from DVD, either my BIOS fails to boot it EFI, or it fails to repair.

I tried changing BIOS from efi to legacy, but that didn't help much. Here is log:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TmnmRTw7Vd/

Comment: Windows is in UEFI boot mode & Ubuntu is in BIOS boot mode. But you do not show a Windows boot entry in UEFI. Best to only boot in UEFI mode and convert Ubuntu/grub to UEFI (using Boot-Repair in UEFI mode). Check that UEFI Secure boot is off. And Windows fast start up is off. From live installer this will add Windows UEFI entry: `sudo efibootmgr -c  -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi" -d /dev/sda -p 2` or use your Windows repair console to fix.

Comment: Thanks. Please tell  how to fix from Windows, because my BIOS won't let me boot UEFI to Ubuntu from removable media.

Comment: I discovered an interesting workaround: I added Macrium Reflect rescue environment to the Windows boot menu, which automatically adds also the Windows recovery options -- in which I can choose to boot from hard disk, and that takes me straight to grub, and from there I am booted into Ubuntu, no questions asked.

Comment: I succeeded in EUFI boot from flash drive, by renaming a file in it. "I went into the folder EFI \ BOOT and renamed the file grubx64.efi to mmx64.efi

Reboot the machine and it should work.

Hope that helps." https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx-64-not-found    Then, boot-repair running from Ubuntu on flash drive was able to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Ubuntu 18.10 on XPS 15 - EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found)