# Can’t choose installation type or install Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, live-usb, usb-drive, usb-installation

I don't know why, but i have a unique problem I've never seen. I've been looking everywhere for weeks and I can't find a solution. Immediately when I boot up Ubuntu a black screen with white text says something along the lines of

> "something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed"

and more errors saying file not found. Right after this I'm able to boot up Ubuntu though, strange as it is.

This is what I've done:

1. Disable secure boot,
2. disable fast boot,
3. shrink 150gb from my 1tb ssd hard drive, and it is unallocated.
4. Burn Ubuntu 18.04 LTS onto a SanDisk flash drive with Rufus 3.4.
5. Click f12 after restarting my laptop.
6. Select boot from SanDisk(Flash drive).
7. Then when I go to install it something very weird happens.

These are the pictures of the order of installation. Keep in mind, I did not skip a single step, and it doesnt show me possible installation types.

My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 5570 1tb SSD Intel i7 core processor. I have tried
ubuntu 18.04, ubuntu 18.1, xubuntu, linux mint and more but the same thing
always happens. I've also gotten help from someone during the process, and they
were very confused on why it happened. Please help, and thanks a lot for reading
all of this.

BTW: I’m trying to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10, also when I click the + or
change it freezes the installer, and it says it is not responding shortly
after. Also I get an error message when I boot Ubuntu. It’s pretty fast but one
thing I remember is “import_mok_state() failed” and some others. It boots fine
after that, but the installation is bugged. I’ve used Rufus 3.4, 3.0, 3.1, and
win32 but none work.

Important: This is what the installation type looks like for me, I did nothing else to it: https://ibb.co/3MRxK7B

UPDATE: I solved the import_mok_state() error but now I get an error saying “AE_NOT_FOUND” and “Couldn’t get size.”

Comment: Possibly related: [System fails to boot with \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1798171). Possible workaround?: [copy /EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi to /EFI/BOOT/mmx64.efi](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1798171/comments/37).

Comment: Possible duplicate: Same workaround [described here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1085638/8005).

Comment: Want to say real quick, I followed the solution and it didn’t work still. It solved the import mok state error but the exact same problem is still occurring. I saw very brief stuff but the same screen pops up, now saying something like “couldn’t get size ” and “AE_NOT_FOUND” or something

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Ubuntu 18.10 on XPS 15 - EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found)