# Installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS freezes when "installing the grub2 package"

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I am having a serious issue installing Ubuntu 18.04 from a Rufus formatted USB drive. The installation goes fine expect when it gets to installing grub2 where the installation freezes and I need to perform a hard reset.

I am installing this on an HP Z2 desktop and I have installed Ubuntu on several other machines in the past and never had this issue. I have tried disabling fast boot etc in the BIOS menu and attempting to installer older versions of Ubuntu but to no avail.

I have also tried opening Ubuntu in the "try Ubuntu" mode and using the boot repair tool but this doesn't help either.

Before I had encountered this issue I was having another issue where the machine wasn't reading the USB drive and I was getting the following message "\EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found" but I managed to solve it here [Can't install Ubuntu 18.10 on XPS 15 - EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found).

The workaround that I used involved going into EFI/BOOT and making a copy of grubx64.efi and renaming it as mmx64.efi so I don't know if this is part of the problem? But the grubx64.efi file is still there and if I don't do this then I can't start the installation.

Any help that could be provided would be greatly appreciated

Comment: youcan't write changes to the EFI partition? it's read only? what's the current state?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure that I understand the question. I meant that I made changes to the USB drive that I am using to make the installation so it is just the rufus formatted drive that I am changing the file grub264.efi to mmc64.efi

Comment: what? why? don't do that. of course that won't work. It looks like a hyberfile lock issue to me but I could be wrong.

Comment: The reason I did this is because it won't boot at all and I can't even run the installer without this fix. I had the same issue encountered here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found

Comment: I know but that sounds like adding gasoline to a fire to me, you didn't address the root cause.

Comment: Well my issue now is that I am unable to load the installer as everytime I try and load the usb I get the error message that mmx64.efi is not found

Comment: you have windows already installed correct? I know it's possible you're on a Legacy (MBR) windows in which case you would have to make a Legacy (MBR) ubuntu key to go with your non efi-capable system.

Comment: Unfortunately no. opted to erase the disk during my installation because I only wanted to use ubuntu

Comment: did you run `powercfg -h off` in an admin cmd on windows beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

Hey people with a HP Z2 and the same problem as above:

Upgrade your firmware to the latest version and Ubuntu 18 and GRUB 2 will install just fine on a UEFI system and secure boot turned off

> Legacy disable secure boot **disable**

For me, the online update tool in BIOS would not work, I had to manually update the firmware with a memory stick.

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.