# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, windows, uefi

I tried to replace Windows 10 with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my Lenovo T480-S via a bootable USB. The installation process went smoothly, however once it finished installing I received a notification that I needed to restart my computer. I selected the option to restart and in the process of booting back up i received an error displaying this:

Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mx64.efi - Not found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\mx64.efi: Not found
Failed to start MokManager: Not found
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed
:Not found

So now i'm stuck without a working OS on my Lenovo. Windows seems to have been removed but Ubuntu will not load.
I will mention that during the installation process i selected the option to install third party hardware and LVM. I'm unsure if this caused this problem..Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Ubuntu 18.10 on XPS 15 - EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i figured it out! In case any one else is having this issue.. I went into the USB's EFI/BOOT folder on a separate laptop that i have and made a copy of the grubx64.efi file and rebooted my computer. Once i rebooted it, i went back into the EFI/BOOT Folder and deleted the copy. This enabled me to boot the USB properly once more on my Lenovo without any issues. It turns out the issue was selecting the third party installation option in the beginning...

Answer (score 0):

First of all installing third party app hasn't caused the problem. While installing Ubuntu along with windows there comes an option install along with windows or erase disk and install ubuntu, I think you have opted 2nd option so Ubuntu has failed to install and also removed windows. As mentioned that you don't have any OS now on your system, now you have 2 options either dual boot your system or have any one OS.
Installing one OS is easy if you want to dual boot then google it follow the steps.

Note :- if you want to install ubuntu go for 16.04 or 19.04 as 17.04 isn't stable and 18.04 have some wifi issues on some systems.

Comment: Thanks for the response and suggestions, but I was able to resolve the issue. My original intentions were to actually replace Windows with Ubuntu. It's working fine now fortunately, as well as the wi-fi connectivity.