# How to put a "boot" flag to my EFI partition

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning

So, I'm on windows and I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu in a second drive, but every time I boot into the live usb, it comes up with an error saying: "Failed to open EFI BOOT mmx.efi - Not found". This error happened every time I tried booting from a live Ubuntu usb. After searching it up, I learnt that I needed to create a new efi partition with a "boot" flag. So, how to do that, or do I need to make a new partition. Also, I can't boot from usb, so GParted won't help. Is there any way I can assign this boot flag from dispart or something?

Ty
--nic

also, I'm completly new to linux so I might not get everything the next time around, and might need much more detailed explanations.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your question is missing important details. Please edit your question and add the new information. Are you trying to put Ubuntu in a second drive? When do you get this error, while booting Live USB or when trying to install Ubuntu, or after Ubuntu installation when you try to boot from the internal drive?

Comment: The ISO filesystem basically meets the qualifications for an EFI partition, so in /EFI/BOOT you should have BOOTx64.EFI,  grubx64.efi, and  mmx64.efi.  Which version Ubuntu are you installing, and how did you create the install media?

Comment: I'm trying to install version 18.04 LTS. Also, I used rufus, following this guide: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

Comment: If you do not have it, some just copy grubx64.efi & rename to mmx64.efi. The mmx64.efi is only required if using UEFI Secure boot and need to install proprietary drivers as then you have to provide a key. Ubuntu cannot provide key for other proprietary software. Can't install Ubuntu 18.10 on XPS 15 9570 - EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi not found
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found

Comment: @oldfred Please post the above comment as an answer and then PM me so that I can upvote it,

Comment: @karel should not the upvote be to the link I posted as that is the answer.

Comment: I already upvoted that.