# Why after successfully running an Ubuntu installation image on PC several times, it suddenly have "serious" problem to load?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, live-usb

I just was playing around today with my 17 partitions of various FS on my 4 HDDs (2 readonly because already some sectors had gone bad) and 1 SSD, all MBR right now, and all this actually doesn't even matter, bacause just today I ran Ubuntu 18.04 installation from USB live flashdrive several times without any problems, just looking around, checking my ext4 partitions, checking what do i need to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, and what are the options.

About two hours ago, I booted through my UEFI BIOS, which settings i just don't change, except for choosing what to boot (which seems to change boot priority sometimes). I was running Ubuntu installation which is sitting on my flashdrive all day seemingly untouched, checking whatever (only having a look), then I booted in Windows, created some partitions on my SSD, then tried to reboot to Ubuntu... and got an issue described on the page below.

[Can't install Ubuntu 18.10 on XPS 15 - EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found)

What I mean is I think I didn't do anything to cause this.

I tried to boot in not UEFI mode, it obviously failed. I thought why the hell such an important file was suddenly missing on my flashdrive, because it seemed fine. I booted Windows, checked the flashdrive. That `\EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi` indeed wasn't there, I thought i'll reformat the flashdrive to FAT32 and do USB live media again. The file wasn't there. I tried to boot and it behaved just the same way, reproducing the same issue.

So, as stated in an answer to the question above, you probably solve this problem by renaming the file `grubx64.efi` to `mmx64.efi`. Ok, but why do I have to do that in the first place?

Last time I was using a PC was about a year ago, now I kind of didn't need anything new to do all I need, I was using all the familiar tools that I have used many times. Again I stumbled upon this fairly wierd situation, even though it solves quickly (thank God), I find myself not having any clue *why*.

So I guess my main question would be:
***How on Earth a bootloader requires that `mmx64.efi` that isn't there?***

As a programmer after a short retirement or a long vacation, I now have concern about in what situation a bootloader can use `grubx64.efi` and `mmx64.efi` in another. And for the sake of science, ***how do I make the flashdrive boot without changing the installation image?*** I would also appreciate ***references for further reading***, as I want to become more fluent in 'such stuff'. Maybe even a book, if there is any. I seem to lack some deep understanding of underlying processes, so to speak.

Comment: I simply don't have enough reputation to ask this in comments to that answer, so I had to create separate question. Sorry about that :)