# Is xubuntu installation taking too long?

Tags: boot, xubuntu, uefi

So here is the problem. I have a packard bell desktop that had windows 8 installed but not really working. Long story short: I was installing xubuntu 18.04 when electricity went down.

When I was able to turn on the computer, [this error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found) showed up. I found some info online about the fact that I needed the **mmx64.efi** file hence I downloaded the latest version of xubuntu, i.e. 19.10, that has it. I used etcher to put the iso into a working USB and then I started the installation again.

Now it has been 24 hours of something. The installation is not stuck since the terminal from the installation window is sending messages but still I believe something is wrong.

I found [this tutorial](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147295) but I am unsure of what to do now. Should I restart the installation or should I wait? Any clues?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I wanted a fresh install, so I choose to let xubuntu erase the disk and partition it accordingly to its needs.

Comment: The average installation time for 18.04 (I think the stats were for) was ~17 minutes, so it feels like something is wrong with your install. Yes speed varies on machine resources, but no 24hrs+   Did you verify your download? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and then write to media (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck) as otherwise you need to check logs to ensure squashfs errors aren't occurring which would explain a super-slow install (using "*Check disc for defects*" is far faster & easier!)

Comment: @guiverc, done everything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I did it. Basically I had to partition the system manually, instead of let Xubuntu doing it.

I followed the partition scheme that I found [here](https://www.tecmint.com/ubuntu-19-04-installation-on-uefi-firmware/) and now everything works fine.