# UEFI boot gone catastrophically sideways

Tags: boot, 18.04, uefi

I have an Acer Travelmate P240 N16Q1 which had happily been single-booting Ubuntu 14.04, and this weekend I decided to upgrade to 18.04. Which is where things have gone off the rails.

Following (attempted) installation, I'm getting the following error message:

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efl - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\Boot\mmx64.efl: Not Found
Failed to start MokManager: Not Found
Something has gone seriously wrong: Import_mok_state() failed
 : Not Found
```

It is now not possible to boot anything while UEFI is on. If I switch from UEFI to Legacy, I can boot USBs, but as soon as I turn UEFI back on, I get the above message. No matter what I'm trying to boot.

I booted boot-repair in Legacy mode, and the results are at http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ykq8nxdGkV/

BIOS setting are limited. There are no options regarding fastboot, etc. Secure Mode is "regular" (with no programs specified) and TPM is off.

As noted, this was working happily until the upgrade. All advice deeply appreciated.

Thanks, S

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Ubuntu 18.10 on XPS 15 - EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

The path on this wound up being slightly different than indicated.

I created a SysRescue live USB, booted that, mounted sda1, went to /EFI/boot. There was neither a mmx64.efi nor grubx64.efi ***BUT*** up in /EFI/ubuntu, there was a mmx64.efi.

I copied that over, sync'd, rebooted. And it works. Some squawking about setting up MOK, easily ignored.

The referenced prior art was a helpful clue, but not a sufficient solution. Thanks!