# Difficulty in booting ubuntu through usb

Tags: system-installation

The `Import_mok_state failed` msg is coming on the screen after clicking on boot from usb. 
Why is this error coming again and again? I have windows 10 per-installed in hp laptop.

Comment: We need more information in order to help you. 1. Please describe the computer: brand name and model; 2. Did you [check that the download was good](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)? 3: How did you create the USB boot drive (which tool)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Ubuntu 18.10 on XPS 15 - EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found)