# virtualbox ubuntu no boot /EFI/BOOT/mm64.efi

Tags: boot, virtualbox, uefi

I have installed virtualbox from terminal
`sudo apt-get install virtualbox`
Virtualbox asks for a password while installing.
After restarting, computer says:

> Failed to open /EFI/BOOT/mm64.efi : NOT FOUND
>
> Failed to load image /EFI/BOOT/mm64.efi : NOT FOUND
>
> Failed to start MokManager : NOT FOUND
>
> Something has gone seriously wrong: Import_mok_state() failed : NOT FOUND

And after some seconds the laptop turns off again.
I tried pressing Left Shift while system starts nothing happened.
Cannot access boot directory to boot from usb.
System does not boot from bootable usb.
Greatly appreciate help, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Ubuntu 18.10 on XPS 15 - EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Hit Assist key on Sony Vaiothen press start button. press F2 to open menu.

Comment: The question is about a virtual machine.

Comment: @guntbert I don't think the question was about Virtual Machine. In my interpretation, the issue occurred after OP installed *VirtualBox in Ubuntu* not *Ubuntu in VirtualBox* since they said ***And after some seconds the laptop turns off again***.

Comment: @mysicAngel Is your issue solved? Can you please elaborate what you did after opening the menu?