# How do I make /boot/efi writeable under a Live Session?

Tags: permissions, uefi, live-usb, live-environment

I am trying to fix a specific problem ([this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230318/vaio-tap-20-unable-to-clean-install-ubuntu-20-04-multiple-issues)) and a solution that somebody else has suggested involves me re-naming a particular file under a *live session* of Ubuntu... But I cannot seem to make `/boot/efi` writable.

I have tried various suggestions I found online, but they all relate to an *installed session* and when I try the same with a *live session*, Ubuntu just whinges at me that it's "not allowed".

Another thing I tried, which someone suggested elsewhere is this, from root (/)...

Input:

```
fdisk -l
```

Output:

```
/dev/sdb1 (type is "empty")
/dev/sdb2 (type is "EFI")
/dev/sdb3 (type is Linux)
```

Input:

```
mkdir efi
```

Output:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory 'efi': Permission denied
```

Input:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb2
```

Output:

```
mount: /dev/sdb2: can't find in /etc/fstab
```

What I want is to delete mmx64.efi and rename grubx64.efi as mmx64.efi (I figure if I am going to rename grubx64.efi as mmx64.efi, I might as well delete mmx64.efi *first*), like is discussed over [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found) ([my problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230318/vaio-tap-20-unable-to-clean-install-ubuntu-20-04-multiple-issues) is different, but very, *very* similar and it has been suggested that [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found) might fix [my problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230318/vaio-tap-20-unable-to-clean-install-ubuntu-20-04-multiple-issues) as well).

Comment: Have you tried unmounting `/boot/efi` and remounting it with the `rw` option?

Comment: I used sudo -o remount,rw '/' to make the filesystem writable (I need to delete one file and rename another, both under /cdrom/EFI/BOOT), I did not see an error, but it dropped to a new line, awaiting the next command... However, when I try to delete and re-name the respective files, it still tells me "read-only file system".

Comment: But  `/boot/efi` is not the root partition. It is a separate partition.

Comment: The files I need to delete and remove are found there (I searched for them and it said that's where the files are)... It's the solution discussed here ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found ) that I am trying, for a very similar problem.

Comment: In Terminal run `sudo -H nautilus`, Nautilus will open and if mounted /boot/efi will be writable. You could also install nautilus-admin.

Comment: sudo -H nautilus opened Nautilus all right, but it didn't make /boot/efi writable...

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong commands, and another user elsewhere assisted me with identifying the correct commands...

cd /tmp
sudo mkdir efi
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 efi
cd /tmp/efi
ls

Once I changed to the relevant directory, I was then able to make the applicable changes:
mv grubx64.efi mmx64.efi

Sadly, [it did not resolve my problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230318/vaio-tap-20-unable-to-clean-install-ubuntu-20-04-multiple-issues), as I now have a similar - albeit slightly different - error message when I try to start my computer...

```
Failed to open |EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi - Not found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi: Not found
start_image() returned Not found
```