Computer bricked - booting from live USB not possible?
I just got a Lenovo laptop (ideapad). To install Ubuntu I created an installation USB stick.
But when I try to boot from that stick, I get the following error:

Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not found Failed to load image
XXX: Not Found Failed to start MokManager: Not Found Something has
gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed: Not Found

Then after 3 seconds, the laptop turns off immediately.
Also the laptop won't boot from the main disk (I guess it's empty?).
So currently the machine is completely bricked. At least I can still enter the UEFI.
How can I fix this and boot from the Ubuntu USB stick?

see if one of these will help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found
